# Client-side access token doesn't function after a server-side call (FB Graph API v2.0)

Tags: facebook-graph-api

First, a facebook user is logged client-side with using Facebook JS SDK.

FB.init() is called with the following parameters:

```
{
  version    : 'v2.0',
  appId: '...',
  status     : true,
  cookie     : true,
  xfbml      : false
}
```

Then, in PHP, a session is created:

```
$session = (new FacebookJavaScriptLoginHelper())->getSession();
```

Once FB API calls have been made from PHP, I still can continue calling FB API from withing js.

But as soon as my page sends a new command to the server instructing it to make an FB API call, it doesn't work the second time, and the FB API says:

> An access token is required to request this resource.

Obviously, this is called one more time and after that it stops working:

```
$session = (new FacebookJavaScriptLoginHelper())->getSession();
```

If the user updates the page in his browser, the next call from the server will work again. What I want instead is to keep querying FB API from both the server and the browser simultaneously without reloading the page.

Answer (score 0):

It is out of date, but maybe will help someone

```
<?php 
//some code here - requires and uses
FacebookSession::setDefaultApplication($SETTINGS['fbappid'], $SETTINGS['fbsecret']);
$helper = new FacebookJavaScriptLoginHelper();

$session;
try {
    $session = $helper->getSession();
} catch(FacebookRequestException $ex) {
    //
} catch(\Exception $ex) {
    //
}

?>

<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <title></title>
    </head>
    <body>
    <script>
    window.fbAsyncInit = function() {
        FB.init({
            appId      : '<?php echo $SETTINGS['fbappid'] ?>',
            xfbml      : true,
            version    : 'v2.0',
            status     : true,
            cookie     : true
        });


        FB.getLoginStatus(function(response) {
            if (response.status === 'connected') {          
                var uid = response.authResponse.userID;
                var accessToken = response.authResponse.accessToken;
                FB.login(function () {
                    FB.api('/me', {
                            fields: 'id'
                        }, function (response) {
                            console.log(response);
                        });
                }, {
                    scope: 'publish_actions'
                });
            } else if (response.status === 'not_authorized') {

            } else {

            }
        });

    };


    (function(d, s, id){
        var js, fjs = d.getElementsByTagName(s)[0];
        if (d.getElementById(id)) {return;}
        js = d.createElement(s); js.id = id;
        js.src = "//connect.facebook.net/en_US/sdk.js";
        fjs.parentNode.insertBefore(js, fjs);
    }(document, 'script', 'facebook-jssdk'));

    </script>
    <div id="fb-root"></div>
<?php
//here url to go to my app
echo "<a href='...'>Sign in to Facebook application</a>";

if ($session) {
    echo "<br/>logged in";
}
?>

    </body>
</html>
```

Note that login comes after second access to page if cookies were not set. So ajax request is needed to check properly.